# PHP - DateTime format returns the days as 1

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I have been having this problem for a while; The date sets only the days as 01 when they arnt.
This is my php code:

```
echo $_POST['day']; //This returns 23
// Year - 1995 Month - 9
$datet = new DateTime($_POST['year'] . "-" . $_POST['month'] . "-" . $_POST['day']);
$date = $datet->format('Y-m-d');
echo $date; //This returns 1995-09-01
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: 1995-09-23 That is the date I expect to show up.

Comment: http://ideone.com/iPUaDs

Comment: Wait, you already have it in year-month-day format and you need it in year-month-day format through some complicated function calls because?

Comment: I think @MarkBaker just called you a liar.

Comment: I need to send it to MySQL

Comment: Is DateTime expecting a single string with YYYY-MM-DD or some other format, such as YYYY-DD-MM (and your MM is out of range)?

Comment: @MarkBaker echos: 23 September 1995 date echo:1995-09-01 Just tested this exact code you wrote just added echo for each post

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing date through constructor you can set it.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate ($_POST['year'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['day']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The $_POST['day'] returned a string, and for some reason when the formatter takes a string it will just set the value to 1..
So I changed it to intval ($_POST['day'])